# SEM: Difference between unidentified, underidentified, and underdetermined models?

Tags: terminology, structural-equation-modeling, identifiability

It's been asserted to me that there is a difference between underidentified and unidentified models in that:

> Underidentified models can still be estimated and solutions can be
> obtained, but they are usually considered to be less reliable because
> they may result in multiple solutions or solutions that are far from
> the true parameters.
>
> On the other hand, models are said to be unidentified when there is no
> information in the data to estimate any of the parameters, either
> because the model is overly complex or because the data is simply not
> informative enough.

Meanwhile the same interlocutor believes that underdetermined and underidentified models really are just the same thing.

I'd never heard of a distinction being drawn between underidentified and unidentified models, and thought they both meant "not identified". Is the distinction being drawn accurate, and does it even make sense? If so, can anyone given a realistic example of a situation in which there is "no information in the data to estimate any of the parameters".

Answer (score 3):

I had never encountered the terms *underidentified* nor *unidentified*. However, they remind me of the following concepts:

1. **Structural non-identifiability**: which is an intrinsic property of a model, for which different combinations of its parameters would yield exactly the same output. For instance, if the relation between the input $x$ and the output $y$ is $y = (A+B)x$ (with free parameters $A$ and $B$), then the model is said to be structurally non-identifiable.
2. **Practical non-identifiability**: this is a property of your experimental setting, in which the parameters of an otherwise structurally identifiable model cannot be accurately determined due to observations being scarce and/or noisy, for instance.

You can check the following answers and papers:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/474138/271601
- https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2020.558477/full

Comment: This does seem highly similar to the SEM literature, where the same distinction is drawn between "empirical underidentification", and identification due to intrinsic properties of the model.